# How to deal with IDA auto-analysis analyzing invalid paths?

Tags: ida, idapython, deobfuscation

Obfuscation techniques such as opaque predicates often trick IDA's auto-analysis into creating incorrect or contradicting interpretations of the code under analysis.

There is some mention of controlling IDA's auto-analysis via hooks on the [IDA website](https://www.hex-rays.com/blog/improving-ida-analysis/), however I cannot find other references to this online.

In my case, I have a list of known-valid branches and I want IDA to "prefer" these branches during auto-analysis in order to avoid sp-analysis and invalid decompilation issues.

I have been able to essentially mimic this functionality by scripting my own analysis pass that ignores non- known-valid branches, but I wonder if there is an easier way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Last time I had that a problem like that, I loaded the executable with auto-analysis disabled, then ran a script that detected valid and invalid branches, and patched the valid branches to be non-conditional and nopped out the invalid branches. After that, I just enabled auto-analysis, and as the invalid branches were removed, the analysis results were fine.

Of course, this depends on being able to find the valid and invalid branch *instructions*, not just their *targets*. I am unsure what you mean by "a list of known-valid branches", but in case you know the location of the valid branch instructions, or you can write a simple analyzer that detects the patterns with invalid branches, a preprocessor might be a good way to handle the problem.

Comment: I've used techniques like these in situations like these. Here are two of my publications that explain them, and provide source code: http://www.msreverseengineering.com/blog/2015/6/29/transparent-deobfuscation-with-ida-processor-module-extensions
http://www.msreverseengineering.com/blog/2018/1/23/a-walk-through-tutorial-with-code-on-statically-unpacking-the-finspy-vm-part-one-x86-deobfuscation